# Barcode printing in oracle form (ora 12c) using id automation

Tags: linux, oracle, oraclereports, barcode-printing

we are using oracle reports 12c to print the barcode (without check digit) using IDAutomation font. Barcode format used is code `128B`. We are not printing this report/barcode directly to printer, instead we are showing preview in pdf. This application is hosted on a Linux server.

Issue:

The barcode printed are not recognised by some scanners (scanners from medical equipment). If we try same thing by hosting application in windows server then barcode is recognised by all scanners.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, in order to display the font correctly, it has to be installed on the server.

From what you described, it seems that the barcode font is installed on your Windows server, but is not on Linux server. I know nothing about Linux so I don't know *how* to do that, but - I hope you do, or you have someone (sysadmin?) who is capable of checking that.

Comment: thanks for reply,we have font installed on linuxs erver as well(idautomation code128)